# Gradient color not showing in IE 9

Tags: css, asp.net, devexpress, internet-explorer-9, gradient

Gradient color is not showing in ie9, but works fine for other browsers, I have attached sample code for your reference.please give suggestions on the same.

**scenario**:
On devexpress grid row hover, change the background color to gradient color.

**CSS**

```
  <style>

  .dxgvDataRow:hover {
   color: #FFFFFF !important;
   background:rgba(108,195,221,0.95) ; 
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%, rgba(108,195,221,0.95) 100%) !important; /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(135,224,253,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(108,195,221,0.95))) !important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%,rgba(108,195,221,0.95) 100%) !important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%,rgba(108,195,221,0.95) 100%) !important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%,rgba(108,195,221,0.95) 100%) !important; /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%,rgba(108,195,221,0.95) 100%) !important; /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#f26cc3dd',GradientType=0 ) !important; /* IE6-9 */
    }
    </style>
```

**Aspx page**

```
   <div class="MainDiv">
     <div class="table-responsive">  
       <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdProjects" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ProjectId" ClientInstanceName="grdProjects" Width="100%" >
            <Styles Header-HorizontalAlign="Center" Header-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                Header-Font-Bold="true">
            </Styles>
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Job #" Width="70px" FieldName="ProjectId" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains" VisibleIndex="1">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Tool" FieldName="Tool" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                   

            </Columns>
             <SettingsPager PageSize="5">
                    <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" />
                </SettingsPager>

            </dx:ASPxGridView>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Code**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {    
        DataSet dsgrdfrmMyjob = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtfrmds = new DataTable();
        dsgrdfrmMyjob.ReadXml(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ProjectHistory.xml"));

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn ProjectId = new DataColumn();
        ProjectId.ColumnName = "ProjectId";
        ProjectId.DataType = typeof(int);
        dt.Columns.Add(ProjectId);

        DataColumn Job = new DataColumn();
        Job.ColumnName = "Job";
        Job.DataType = typeof(string);
        dt.Columns.Add(Job);

        DataColumn Tool = new DataColumn();
        Tool.ColumnName = "Tool";
        Tool.DataType = typeof(string);
        dt.Columns.Add(Tool);
        dt.Clear();
        dtfrmds.Clear();
        dtfrmds = dsgrdfrmMyjob.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow item in dtfrmds.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
        }


        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdProjects.DataSource = dt;
            grdProjects.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grdProjects.DataSource = null;
            grdProjects.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: IE9 doesn't support gradients. http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient

Answer (score 0):

CSS gradient will wont work in IE9, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

To avoid this kind of issue, give solid `background-color` before the CSS gradient background.